# Trying to make user authorization more DRY with pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I am using pundit to handle authorizations in a ruby on rails app and I want to see if the user who is logged in can moderate before showing delete and edit buttons for posts, comments, etc.

Here's the original working method in post policy, comment policy etc

```
 def destroy
   user.present? && (user == record.user || user.role?(:admin) || user.role?(:moderator))
 end
```

Here's the new method I added to application policy

```
  def can_moderate?(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
    user == record.user || user.role?(:admin) || user.role?(:moderator)
  end
```

Here's the DRYer post policy I'm working on

```
  def destroy?
    user.present? && user.can_moderate?
  end
```

This DRYer version gives me an undefined error method for can_moderate. 
Any thoughts on why?

Thanks!

EDIT TO ADD FULL ERROR

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `can_moderate?' for #<User:0xb5671e60>):
14:     <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
15:       <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
16:     <% end %>
17:     <% if policy(@post).destroy? %>
18:       <%= link_to "Delete", [@topic, @post], method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this topic?' } %>
19:     <% end %>
20:   </div>
app/policies/post_policy.rb:7:in `destroy?'
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb___159039275__620331048'
```

Comment: I would suggest you to go ahead and paste the entire error here. From the description of the question you are getting an undefined error for ```can_moderate``` but the method name is ```can_moderate?```. Also where do you have the method mentioned? Same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tien,

Do not call the `can_moderate?` on the user object. It would assume the `can_moderate?` is present in the user class/model. Instead just call the method since in the present in same file/controller.

```
  def destroy?
    user.present? && can_moderate?
  end
```

Also you can have your can_moderate? method to just

```
  def can_moderate?(user, record)
    user == record.user || user.role?(:admin) || user.role?(:moderator)
  end
```

Comment: Ah got it now. For some reason I thought I needed to call it on a specific user. So it works magically from the current_user since I'm using devise. Thanks!

Comment: Since `can_moderate?` is in the application policy, it should not have arguments, in fact that code as it is will throw an `ArgumentError` for expecting 2 but got 0. Those variables are available through `attr_accessor` methods.

Answer (score -1):

DRYer version,

```
# policy file
def destroy?
  can_moderate?
end

def can_moderate?(user, record)
  user.present? && user == record.user ||
                   user.role?(:admin)  || user.role?(:moderator)
end
```